# Besides iCloud or a sync cable, how can i back up my files?

Tags: icloud, backup, data-synchronization, data-transfer

I've got an iPhone 5 running iOS8. It can't use a sync cable, because it came broken when I bought it used in January 2015 (no returns accepted, and no resale value if it's broken, so I just kept it, but barely use it, would prefer to stop using it altogether, and only haven't yet because there are files still stuck on it).

I just spent like two hours trying to upload my photos to Google Drive and Onedrive, and I only just figured out how, because the apps I was using seem to be designed to give the user a hard time with uploading (Drive app doesn't seem to have an Upload option, Photos forces me to select files one by one instead of hitting Select All, Photos forces me to only upload ten files to Drive at a time, drive.google.com doesn't work on my iPhone when I try it, etc).

I've figured out how to back up photos (using the Onedrive app works well enough), but I still don't know how to back up my files from the Notes app, the videos from an app called Download,and the audio files from Smart Recorder and Voice Memos. These apps don't have a "share" option built in, and I don't have or know of any app that can access those apps' files (I tried Onedrive, and it only lets me to choose files from Photos).

Is there any way I haven't thought of to transfer these files to another device? I'd prefer not to resort to copying my Notes into emails, recording the playback of my audio files with another device and filming the screen of my iPhone as it plays my video files, because doing all those things would take forever.

Comment: Why can't you use iCloud?

Comment: I thought iCloud was just a way of syncing between Apple devices. I don't have another Apple device, and I don't want one. I mentioned above that I want to stop using my iPhone, but left out that that was because I prefer Android devices and not just because my iPhone is broken.

Comment: And iCloud only backs up files from certain apps, but leaves others out.

Comment: @c0n You are mistaken. iCloud backs up everything on your iPhone—every game's data, every app's data, your health data, your messages, your phone logs, your settings, your Homekit data, your photos and videos, everything. If you get a new iPhone, when setting it up, you can choose to set it up from a backup, and that new phone will have all of the data your current phone has. The sync is as complete as backing it up to a Mac. Also—try the Google Photos (not Google Drive) app for awesome photo backups.

Comment: Edited my answer with more information, in case you weren't notified.

Answer (score 1):

### If you plan on getting another iPhone

iCloud backs up everything on your iPhone—every game's data, every app's data, your health data, your messages, your phone logs, your settings, your Homekit data, your photos and videos, everything. If you get a new iPhone, when setting it up, you can choose to set it up from a backup, and that new phone will have all of the data your current phone has. The sync is as complete as backing it up to a Mac. Also—try the Google Photos (not Google Drive) app for awesome photo backups.

If you need any help backing your phone up with iCloud or iTunes, [check out Apple's support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977).

**Note**: you can very easily get a new sync cable for your iPhone from Amazon. [Here's a reliable one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010S9M3L6), and it's just $6.

---

### If you plan on switching to Android or you're not sure what your next phone will be

Save your photos with Google Photos: download the app for iOS and it's really easy to back up all of your photos, and since Google Photos comes preinstalled on many Android phones (and is available from the Play Store on all others), your photos will be right there waiting for you.

Save contacts by going to iCloud.com and exporting them all as a VCard, then importing this into your Gmail contacts; see a guide here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH3606?locale=en_US.

Notes synced to your Gmail account are just waiting out there in your google account, but notes synced to your iCloud account must be manually exported with Copy and Paste. Here's Apple's official guide on exporting your iCloud notes:

> To copy notes, open the Notes app at iCloud.com. Copy the text of each
>   note and paste it into a document on your computer, such as a Pages or
>   TextEdit document. Save the document to your computer. To export your
>   notes as PDF, open the Notes app in OS X Mountain Lion or later.
>   Select the note, then click File > Export as PDF and choose a
>   location.

Emails are self-explanatory, just hook up the Gmail app on your next phone.

Calendars are pretty self-explanatory too, they should all be tied to accounts in the cloud you can sign in to on an Android phone.

Your phone number is hooked up to your Sim card, but be sure to deactivate iMessage if you switch to Android or you won't get some text messages! Here's a guide on that: http://www.imore.com/how-to-disable-deactivate-imessage-iphone-ipad

Anything else on your phone can likely be exported in its own way, and more than you may realize is tied to the cloud.

Comment: For me a new iPhone isn't an option. I left this out of my description so as not to offend anyone, but I prefer Android, and don't intend to buy another Apple device even though I can.

Comment: @c0n Ok. I added tons of information about syncing data between iPhones/Android phones that will definitely help you out; let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to back up is to purchase a new lightning to USB cable. You can easily get all your photos and videos off the device, and many other apps support using iTunes to retrieve app data. The ability to jump from app to app with a mouse or trackpad rather than tapping and sharing on the iPhone screen makes the process more efficient and less frustrating.

http://www.howtogeek.com/215969/use-itunes-file-sharing-to-copy-files-back-and-forth-with-apps-on-your-iphone-or-ipad/

Comment: Looks like I wasn't very clear. What I meant was that the phone itself doesn't recognize sync cables, not that the sync cable is broken.

Comment: But the phone charges, presumably over a sync cable?

Answer (score -2):

Use a NAS as your backup solution.
Please see the link https://www.synology.com/en-global/solution/Apple
I have got DS216 as home&office backup solution, it works very well for backing up windows laptop, MAC books and iPhone(s). Can also setup a quickConnect, which allows you to access your files in the cloud as long as your NAS is running.

Comment: Please use links, explanations, source declarations, and suggestions to back up your answer.